# Insert a function call in an ELF executable

Tags: elf, patching, instrumentation

I want to patch an ELF executable to insert a function call (the function `s2e_rawmon_loadmodule` and its dependencies are to be linked statically, preferably) at the beginning.

[This answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/192) seems to have a nice set of pointers. If I have understood correctly, dynamic instrumentation using PIN/Valgrind/DynamoRIO alters the address space. The addresses of the subsequent instructions get changed which I don't want.

For static instrumentation, [ERESI project](http://www.eresi-project.org/) could have been useful. But, it looks like the project has been abandoned for long. I am not being able to build the tool on Ubuntu 14.04 due to compilation issues.

Can anybody help me out with some workaround?

Comment: I don't understand if the function you want to call is already in the binary or not, and/or if you want to modify just one binary or to design a generic way to do it. I'd say you could just create a new section manually, drop your code in it (and the first few instructions of OEP), and put a JMP at the OEP.

Comment: would you post the link to your compilation issues ?

Comment: OK, I built it on ubuntu 14.04. The only issue I encountered was usage of word __unbounded in entry.c which ( word __unbounded) can be freely removed without any problem.

Comment: @ws Yes, it works fine with __unbounded deleted. But, does that affect the functionality anyway?

Comment: @Dillinur No, the code does not reside in the binary.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock As far as I understand what __unbounded means it shouldn't affect the functionality. As far as I understand it is not supported anyway, which means that if you want to keep the source intact, you may try to use older versions of gcc.

Comment: Thanks! I have compiler ERESI. So far, I haven't been able to figure out what is going on here: http://www.eresi-project.org/browser/trunk/testsuite/elf/etrel_inject/etrel_original. Any insight?

Comment: Both `relinject32` and `relinject64` returns the following error: **[WARNING] : profile_err() is NULL . Reverting to prinf.
 [E] Unable to copy PLT**

Comment: You may try DynInst (which is actively developped), the following phrase in its document "... [Dyninst]... permit the insertion of code
into a computer application that is either running or on disk (... known as static instrumentation...)" suggests that it can response to your need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to run some code in the context of the binary before anything meaningful happens.

You should read some resources about ELF infection, for example on [vxheavens](http://vxheaven.org/lib/vrn00.html) or [here](http://www.hackercurriculum.org/elf).

But since you're trying to *inject*/*execute* `s2e_rawmon_loadmodule` from [s2e](https://github.com/dslab-epfl/s2e/blob/master/docs/Plugins/RawMonitor.rst), maybe you should just use a debugger instead, because I'm quite sure that this is not how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: How come a debugger help me in injecting a function while the target binary is running on a Debian guest inside s2e framework? Of course, `s2e_rawmon_loadmodule` is supposed to be used while source is available. In my case, source is missing, only binary is assumed to be present.

Comment: Because you didn't mentioned that the software was running on a host inside the s2e framework ;)