# How should I go about trying to figure out the programming language that was used?

Tags: linux, executable

I have an executable file and I would like to figure out which programming language was the source code written in. The first step would be to use a disassembler.

What should be done after that ?

Also, I read that determining which libraries are used during runtime would be a good indicator of the programming language being used. How should I determine which libraries are used ?

Comment: Possibly related: [What hints in machine code can point me to the compiler which was used to generate it?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-hints-in-machine-code-can-point-me-to-the-compiler-which-was-used-to-genera) and [What is a FLIRT signature?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175/what-is-a-flirt-signature/)

Comment: What is the targeted OS ? Things might change drastically from one OS to another (and tools too).

Comment: @Emmanuel Ubuntu

Comment: You could use some other compiler identifier tools: Category:Compiler Identifiers - Collaborative RCE Tool Library http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Compiler_Identifiers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I would suggest that you view the executeable with a hex viewer/editor. That way you can see straight away if the compiler embedded any strings as hints. You should also consider that some languages use C as an intermediate language. An example of that would be [f2c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) a Fortran 77 to C compliler. It appears that f2c also links a support library so you would look for that.

As far as determinining which libraries are used on linux you can use the [ldd command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554343/understanding-ldd-output) for dynamic binaries and [nm for static ones](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/71132-static-library-how-do-i-list.html) to dump the symbols. Also there is a [related question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704202/determine-source-language-from-a-binary)

Here is an intersting blog from a fellow RE member about how the binary you have [might not even come from a compiler](http://www.mimisbrunnr.net/~munin/blog/) and how to recognise that.

Comment: Good answer, you'd be surprised how often this low-tech approach works! That aside, even in the `f2c` case you can probably see spot patterns used by the converter to represent Fortran concepts or convert from Fortran to C conventions.

Answer (score 9):

There are several tools that I have used:

1. [PEiD](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.398) (PE iDentifier)
2. I've also followed [this guide](https://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/PEiDSignatures) and converted PEiD signatures to YARA signatures and simply used [YARA](https://code.google.com/p/yara-project/)
3. [TRiD](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) can also provide another way to identify the compiler used

It's also worth mentioning that if you submit a file to [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com), they will run TRiD against your binary.

These tools are not always definitive, but they can generally give you the correct compiler (and therefore language) that was used.